# ASP.Net Cache problem/question. Where and how to cache. | Costum ADO.Net code

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, caching, ado.net

i am developing an ASP.Net e-commerce application.
I use ASP.Net Web Forms.
When i finish the overall application i was consider about Cache some data so the application performance will increase. (bad idea...i must have consider that from the beginning)

I don't use build-in controls such datagrid.
I neather use MS-Sql.

I use MySql server us database and custom UserControls that i develop.
(Custom ADO.Net code)

To get data from the Database i use :

An object that represent the fields of the table IE : 
If my table (MyTable) has :

```
ID , Title, Date
```

I create will create an object like the above :

```
public class MyTable{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public Datetime Date {get;set;}
}
```

To manage fields from the table i use something like above:

```
public class MyTableDatabaseManager{
   //Insert a row 
   public bool insertMyTable(MyTable item){
     //...Open a mysql connection , do job , close it.
   }
   //Update a row 
   public bool updateMyTable(MyTable item){
     //...Open a mysql connection , do job , close it.
   }
   //Delete a row 
   public bool deleteMyTable(MyTable item){
     //...Open a mysql connection , do job , close it.
   }
   //Get one row
   public MyTable deleteMyTable(int id){
     //...Open a mysql connection , do job , close it.
   }
    //Get some rows or all of them
   public List<MyTable> deleteMyTable(int limit,int page,bool Ordering){
     //...Open a mysql connection , do job , close it.
   }
}
```

My questions are:

How can i store some data in the cache so i have not to communicate all the time with the database?

How can i reset the cache programmaticaly when data is changed?

(I know how, but where i put the code:P it can be in the code-behind files when i do changes or insert some values, or somewhere else?)

Output cache don't work for me, because the most of the provided data are user-specific.
(about 80% of them)

Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply insert into the cache with the key being your userId or whatever you want to vary it by.

```
Cache.Insert(yourUserIdOrWhateverKey, yourObject);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Note this cache viewer (also check out the msdn link above)

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aldotnet/examples/cacheviewer.aspx

To remove you can just call

```
Cache.Remove(yourKey);
```

See:
http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-clear-your-ASP-NET-applications-Cache.aspx

To check if your item is in the cache simply do

```
var yourCachedObject = (CustomClass)Cache["YourUserKey"];
if(yourCachedObject == null)
{
   //it wasnt in the cache
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i'm wondering if there was any other method to use, because :
I use pagging, filtering and shorting.. and some data are user specifiec so, if i cache so mutch data would be a problem?

Comment: A cache is a cache. It will use memory no matter what so it's up to you how much to store, what to store, when to remove, etc.

Comment: Thank you very mutch:)
Strong-> Straight forword answer :P That is what i want to hear.

Comment: If i can add as key of cache everything i want is it good to cache like this : key=query , value = object?

Comment: sure as long as that gives you a unique item to cache, I wouldnt see why not. However if its just one user's search and you dont expect them to be running multiple searches at a time, then you may want to cache it based on their user id. If they can have >1 browser window though or search history then I would keep it based on the query.

Comment: Thank you very mutch again:)
I have build an application that auto  generates ADO.NET code (and php:P) for MySql, MsSql,ODBC,SqlLite etc providers alot time ago and i use that.
Now i have refactor this application, and it supports Cache. 
I Also create an interface (IDatabaseManager):) 
I have refactor a site (with 6.000+ unique visitors a day) and about 
and for 3 hours now the site is about 2 times faster than before:D

Again thank you VERY VERY mutch:D
[If you want the above application i can share it with you.]
[It connects to all database servers to retrieve fields etc , too]

Comment: I Scare, if sometime i will forget my head too..:P